# Querying Pivot Task results in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012

I am trying to figure out if there is a way to query Pivot Task results in SSIS before sending it to the Destination table.
I have Pivot results that look like this:

```
ID  Col1    Col2    Col3
5   NULL    Test2   NULL
5   Test1   NULL    NULL
5   NULL    NULL    Test3
```

By doing it in the script to get the results I want, I would do

```
SELECT ID, ISNULL(MAX(Col1),'') +','+ ISNULL(MAX(Col2),'') +','+ ISNULL(MAX(Col3),'') AS FinalColumn FROM tbl GROUP BY ID
```

Which allows me to get the results that I want:

```
ID  FinalColumn
5   Test1, Test2, Test3
```

What would be a quick way to query those pivot results without using any temp tables or a regular table into the destination table?

Thanks!!!

Comment: You currently have data coming in, you perform a pivot operation on it and that generates the first set of data you have. You then wish to collapse it by ID into a concatenated list of values? Would it be equally correct if your results were `5|Test1|Test2|Test3` (so max value per column or is your intention truly the concatenation of those values

Comment: Concatenation is the only intention in this case. Tks.

Comment: Whats the number of rows we are talking about here?

Comment: Is this a debugging scenario?  You can add a Data Viewer to any path in the Data Flow. During debugging this will show the data passed along that path.